# Show HTML errors in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, debugging, google-chrome

Can Google Chrome show HTML errors (e.g. unclosed `<div>` tags)?

If so, how does one do it?

Comment: I use IE9 for this. =( It shows it beautifully in the console. Kinda weird Chrome doesn't.

Comment: I also use IE for html validation. Crazy right? A huge issue with all chrome extensions is that they use a 3rd-party service to validate your html. You might as well just manually use the online validators and skip the security hole of the extensions.

Comment: @mastaBlasta One does not often see a recommendation to use IE to improve security. For [good reason](http://www.cvedetails.com/product/9900/Microsoft-Internet-Explorer.html?vendor_id=26). Especially compared to [Chrome](http://www.cvedetails.com/product/15031/Google-Chrome.html?vendor_id=1224). Using IE to avoid a vulnerability in the W3C site and chrome developer extensions is like using a cat to get rid of fleas.

Comment: @Brian Your comment has nothing to do with anything. Newer versions of IE display errors encountered during the inital parsing of the HTML http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn423949(v=vs.85).aspx#HTML5warnings This is useful for debugging missing tags, invalid nesting, and other trivial (but hard to spot) things on a local environment. As far as I can tell this feature is built directly into the browser and does not require it to talk to an outside server. I have also looked for a similar feature in chrome but haven't found it.

Comment: @mastaBlasta I understand why you would recommend IE; thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Firefox is great for this. View Source shows HTML errors in red, and a tooltip describes the issue: https://i.imgur.com/Ev1LN1l.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

~Use HTML Validator extension.~

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-validator/mpbelhhnfhfjnaehkcnnaknldmnocglk.

Comment: Dead link: Google shows https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-validator/mpbelhhnfhfjnaehkcnnaknldmnocglk now

Answer (score 2):

Another options is to use the W3C validator "favelets" to open the W3C validator from a bookmark.

http://validator.w3.org/favelets.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it can do exactly what you're after without an extension.  You can use the developer tools to explore the HTML to see if it is what you expect/intend, but I don't think it will tell you where there are errors.

HTML browsers are designed to be able to taken invalid markup and render it as best they can. It will have a very high tolerance for errors.

You may want to try an extension like one of [these](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/search?q=w3c+valid).

Answer (score 0):

There is a new HTML5 validator for based on libTidy (same as the firefox version)

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/anjdemaoejlpgmnmkijdemoiebcddhkc

Comment: It's called "Kingsquare HTML Validator". It does show some annoying warnings ("UTF-8 decoding error"). It works locally.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Validity](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/validity/bbicmjjbohdfglopkidebfccilipgeif?hl=en) as it shows errors in the devtools console. It also lets you set up a list of hostnames where it should run on each page load which has been super useful for me during development.